# Different color for different choices in tkinter option menu

Tags: python, colors, tkinter, optionmenu

I am using Python and Tkinter. I have an option menu with three choices with "on" being one of them. I want to make "on" be green when I select it. I don't mean the font. I want the background of the option menu to be green when I select "on" while the other options will just be default gray.

How can I do this? I've seen other posts that just make the whole option menu background a different color, but I only want color when a particular choice is selected. Thank you!

Comment: "I've seen other posts that just make the whole option menu background a different color, but I only want color when a particular choice is selected." Then just have pressing the item in the menu call a method that also changes the color of the background, and have the other two items change the color back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file this under U, for ugly:

```
from Tkinter import *

OPTIONS = (
    "egg",
    "go",
    "spam"
)

controlsMap = {}

root = Tk()

def callbackFunc(name, index, mode):
    value = root.getvar(name) #getvar: return the value of Tcl variable NAME
    widget = controlsMap[name]
    if value == 'go':
        widget.config(bg='green',fg='black',
                 activebackground='green',
                 activeforeground='black')
    else:
        widget.config(bg='SystemButtonFace',fg='SystemButtonText',
                 activebackground='SystemButtonFace',
                 activeforeground='SystemButtonText')


var1 = StringVar(root, name='var1') #give it a master and a name
var1.set(OPTIONS[0])
om1 = OptionMenu(root, var1, *OPTIONS)
om1.config(width=5)
om1.grid(row=0, column=0)
controlsMap['var1'] = om1
var1.trace_variable('w', callbackFunc)

var2 = StringVar(root, name='var2') #
var2.set(OPTIONS[0])
om2 = OptionMenu(root, var2, *OPTIONS)
om2.config(width=5)
om2.grid(row=0, column=1)
controlsMap['var2'] = om2
var2.trace_variable('w', callbackFunc)

var3 = StringVar(root, name='var3') #
var3.set(OPTIONS[0])
om3 = OptionMenu(root, var3, *OPTIONS)
om3.config(width=5)
om3.grid(row=0, column=2)
controlsMap['var3'] = om3
var3.trace_variable('w', callbackFunc)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows you are out of luck because menus are native controls which don't allow this much customization. The same might be true for osx, but I don't remember for certain.

For other platforms you can use the [entryconfigure](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.entryconfigure-method) method of the menu associated with the option menu, which lets you set the background color of each entry in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

you could put a trace on it:

```
from Tkinter import *

OPTIONS = (
    "egg",
    "go",
    "spam"
)

root = Tk()

var = StringVar()
var.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default

def callbackFunc(name, index, mode):
    value = var.get()
    if value == 'go':
        om.config(bg='green',fg='black',
                 activebackground='green',
                 activeforeground='black')
    else:
        om.config(bg='SystemButtonFace',fg='SystemButtonText',
                 activebackground='SystemButtonFace',
                 activeforeground='SystemButtonText')

om = OptionMenu(root, var, *OPTIONS)
om.pack()

Callbackname = var.trace_variable('w', callbackFunc)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If I have several option menus with the same values, is there a way so that they all share the same callback function? I notice in the callbackFunc, you specifically get a variable. Is there a way to make it so that you can send arguments to the callback when you do the trace_variable?